# Query results different in mysql and mariadb

Tags: mysql, mariadb

I use this query in `mariadb` and `mysql`

```
SELECT * FROM DTL_RECEIVES D
WHERE ((D.QTYACL - D.QTYRCV  ) <>0 )
```

In `mysql` I do not have any error.

But in `mariadb` the below error occurred:

> "Data Truncation error occured on a write  of column 0Data was 0 bytes long and 0 bytes were transferred."

FYI:

```
mysql  Ver 14.14 Distrib 5.5.41 for debian-linux-gnu (i686) 
mysql  Ver 15.1  Distrib 5.5.41-MariaDB, for Win64 (x86)
```

Comment: What is the data type you are using, is it a double/float ?

Comment: Please provide `SHOW CREATE TABLE DTL_RECEIVES`.  Did mysql give you a Warning?

Comment: @cjg : the data type of QTYACL and QTYRCV fields are INT(11)

Comment: @RickJames : this 

CREATE TABLE `DTL_RECEIVES` (/n  `VIDRCV` varchar(50) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',/n
 `PARTNUM` varchar(20) NOT NULL,/n 
 `MPRICE` int(10) unsigned DEFAULT NULL,/n  
`QTYACL` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,/n  
`DISCOUNT` int(10) unsigned DEFAULT NULL,/n  
`AMOUNT` int(10) unsigned DEFAULT NULL,/n 
`NQTYRCV` int(10) unsigned DEFAULT NULL,/n 
 PRIMARY KEY (`VIDRCV`,`PARTNUM`)

Answer (score 0):

I suspect it has something to do with subtraction of UNSIGNED.  MariaDB is pickier about being ANSI compliant.

The quick answer might be to change the query to

```
SELECT * FROM DTL_RECEIVES D
WHERE D.QTYACL != D.QTYRCV
```

The better answer would be to make `QTYACL` and `QTYRCV` the same type.  Currently you have one `SIGNED` and one `UNSIGNED`.

Comment: Oops, I was looking at NQTYRCV.  QTYRCV is not defined in D !  No fair !

Comment: sorry for my fault in  table description :) ,, the point is QTYACL int(11) DEFAULT NULL and QTYRCV and QTYRCV int(10) unsigned DEFAULT NULL,, not NQTYRCV ,, thank for your advice

Comment: +1 for @Rick James, alter table DTL_RECEIVES modify QTYRCV int(11) DEFAULT NULL; this script save my time, thank all